# Подтверждение перед отправкой запроса

Tags: javascript

Удаляет товар независимо от ответа "да" или "нет". Как это исправить?

HTML:

```
<a href="index.php?page=tovars&delete=<?=$dost['id'];?>" onclick="doYouWantTo()">
```

JS:

```
function doYouWantTo() {
    doIt = confirm("Вы уверены?");
    if (doIt) {
        //что сюда писать?
    } else {
        // и что сюда?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запрета отправки запроса к серверу достаточно передавать в функцию `doYouWantTo` `event` и в случае получения отказа от пользователя блокировать переход по ссылке, используя `event.preventDefault();`:

```js
function doYouWantTo(event) {
    var doIt = confirm("Вы уверены?");
    if (!doIt) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

```html
<a href="index.php?page=tovars&delete=1" onclick="doYouWantTo(event)">delete</a>
```